How to deploy a SQLite Database with a GO application
I have an application structured more or less like the following :
app
   api
      database
         db.go
      main.go
   data
      database
         data.db
   ui

I would like to connect as a relative path to the data.db. However, I have only been able to successfully do so by using an absolute path from C:\..\..\..etc...\data.db
Below is the following code I have tried. I am getting an "unable to open database file : out of memory (14)
func (d *Database) Connect() {
    var err error
    d.Database, err = gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("data/database/data.db"), &gorm.Config{
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            SingularTable: true,
            NoLowerCase:   true,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database, err: " + err.Error())
    }
}

What do I need to do to get this working? What do I need to consider when deploying to a server?

Use path "./data/database/data.db" perhaps ? Truth be told, an out of memory error does not match with a file not being found. I find it very strange that an absolute path changes anything at all. I would more suspect that a completely different database is being loaded.

Of course an absolute path works: it leads to the db file in the source directory. When the app is compiled, the working directory is irrelevant with an absolute path. However, the database is not automagically included. From what I can see, main.go lies in "api". If compiled and run there, the correct path would be "../data/database/data.db".
